# How to convert a string to a palindrome with minimum number of character replacement such that palindromic string contains a given word?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace, string-algorithm

We have a string `s`, containing lower case alphabets (a-z). We can replace any character with any other character, and we can do this any number of times.

We can to make a palindrome string `p` from `s`, such that the `p` contains a given specific words(i.e. let's suppose `linkedin` ). Now, we need to find the lowest number of insertions which would take to convert string `s` to `p`.

ex - `s` = `linkedininininin`
then the palindrom string `p` would be `linkedinnideknil` and the result would be 6.

second example( to make it more clear) - `s` = `linkaeiouideknil`
then `p` = `linkedinnideknil` and result would be for 4, because we'll replace `a` with `e`, `e` with `d`, `o` and `u` with `n`.

I have tried to solve it by taking the LCS of s and p, and subtracting that from the length of s. but the problem is that how do I make sure that the palindrome is guaranteed to contain that given word(Linkedin)?

Please provide your approach. Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't it be 4? you already have an `ni` in `s` (towards the end)

Comment: We need to make it a palindrome as well

Comment: why not simply create the palindrom?

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly,

You can create the palindrome and then replace the wrong letters in `s`:

```
String s="linkaeiouideknil";
String p="";
String word="linkedin";
char[] wordC = word.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(word);
String drow = sb.reverse().toString();
sb.reverse();
sb.append(drow);
String pali=sb.toString();
char[] sC = s.toCharArray();
sC=Arrays.copyOf(sC, pali.length());
sb.delete(0, sb.length());
int counter=0;
for (int i = 0; i < sC.length; i++) {
    if(sC[i]!=pali.charAt(i)){
        sC[i]=pali.charAt(i);
        counter++;
    }
    sb.append(sC[i]);
}
System.out.println(counter);    
p=sb.toString();
System.out.println(p);
```

the output when run is 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate the string and palindrome simultaneously; inserting characters that don't exist in the input string, and replacing substrings when there is a next available character:

```
public int palindromify(String pal, String read) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(read);
    int insertions = 0; //track insertions
    int palIndex = 0; //our progress through the palindrome
    //caches characters we know aren't further in the input, saves time
    Set<Character> none = new HashSet<>();
    boolean outOfInput = false;
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        if (i >= sb.length()) {
            outOfInput = true; //if we run out of input, we know we have to append remainder
            break;
        }
        if (palIndex >= pal.length()) {
            sb.delete(i, sb.length()); //remove remainder, we're out of palindrome
            break;
        }
        char curr = pal.charAt(palIndex++); //increment palindrome
        if (sb.charAt(i) != curr) {
            //perform lookahead
            boolean found = false;
            if (!none.contains(curr)) { //only search a missing char once
                for (int w = i + 1; w < sb.length(); w++) {
                    if (sb.charAt(w) == curr) {
                        sb.replace(i, w + 1, "" + curr); //replace up to our lookahead
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    none.add(curr);
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                //simply insert our character, later ones are useful for others
                sb.insert(i, curr);
                insertions++; //this was an insertion, one of our counted values
            }
        }
    }
    //if we ran out of input, append the rest of palindrome
    return insertions + (outOfInput ? pal.length() - sb.length() : 0);
}
```

This saves you a lot of copying/iteration/needless work, and should ensure that the maximum amount of iteration is the length of the palindrome read in (or the length of the input, whichever is shorter)

Thus when calling:

```
palindromify("linkedinnideknil", "linkedinininin"); //prints '4'
```

Creating the actual palindrome is pretty easy, and much less work:

```
String s = /* some value */;
s += new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
```

Edit: Not working for some edge cases, fixing.

Comment: The point here is that `p` can easily be built through other means, I avoided finishing the completion of `p` in the method because its value would be lost anyhow by returning the wanted number.

Comment: Good news is my updated answer fully builds it anyhow

Comment: @rouge, It's a bit cumbersome... But I suppose that's just because the question can be understood in a few ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create the palindrome that you want to transform your string into.  Next, calculate the edit distance from your original string to the palindrome you created where your edits are replacing the characters in the string:  no insertions or deletions.  The code would look something like

```
def minReplacements(original, palindrome, m, n):
    # base case:  we're finished processing either string so we're done
    if (m == 0 or n == 0):
        return 0

    # The characters in the string match so find out how many replacements are
    # required for the remaining characters in the strings.
    if (original[m-1] == palindrome[n-1]):
        return minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n-1)

    # Recurse on replacing a character in the original string
    # with a character in the palindrome string
    return 1 + minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n-1)
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to know how many character replacements, inserts or deletes are needed to transform the original string into the palindrome string, then change the last line of the code above with this code:

```
    return 1 + min(minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m, n-1),   # insert character
                   minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n-1), # replace character
                   minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n))   # delete character
```

The code when then look like:

```
def minReplacements(original, palindrome, m, n):
    # base case:  we're finished processing either string so we're done
    if (m == 0):  # done processing original string
        return n  # return the number of characters left in palindrome
    if (n == 0):  # done processing palindrome
        return m  # return the number of characters left in the original string

    # The characters in the string match so find out how many edits are
    # required for the remaining characters in the strings.
    if (original[m] == palindrome[n]):
        return minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n-1)

    # Recurse on editing a character in the original string
    # with a character in the palindrome string
    return 1 + min(minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m, n-1),   # insert character
                   minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n-1), # replace character
                   minReplacements(origininal, palindrome, m-1, n))   # delete character
```